# String Comparison in C strcmp

Tags: c, arrays, string, comparison, multidimensional-array

I have domain names stored in a 2 dimensional array of char

```
char domainNames[2][4096]= {"www.yahoo.com","java.sun.com"};
```

and I need to check if a given domain name stored in another array( `char data[4096];`) exists in the list, if the domain name is found, store all the IP addresses found in `char IP[2][4096]= {"87.248.122.122","192.9.162.55"};` separated by "#" in the array `char msg[4096];`

this is the way I did it:

```
  for (i=0; i< 2;i++)
  {
    if(strcmp(domainNames[i], data)==0)
    {
      strcat(msg, IP[i]);
      strcat(msg, "#");
      found = true;
    }
  }

  if(!found)
    strcpy(msg,"IP not found");

  break;
}
```

The problem is that the result is always "IP not found" even if the string does exist.

Comment: How do you input `data`?

Comment: The code you've shown contains three `}` and only two `{`. Which loop is exited by `break`?

Comment: its a client server application that usese UDP sockets, data is read from the client using recvfrom method

Comment: @Inspired its not the full code, it just a segment, the break is actually a part of a switch statement, but my problem is with the comparison, for some reason it always show that the strings are not equal, am not sure if am dealing with the 2d-array correctly

Comment: example is incomplete, error messages not recorded or shown, example does not compile without work, voting to close

Comment: If you are reading data from client are you sure there are no excess characters like space or newline in the data. If so the comparison will fail.

Comment: @user3108337 There is nothing wrong with `strcmp` usage here. My guess is that you have `\n` at the end of your `data`. I suppose that a simple debug print like `printf("data=[%s]\n", data);` would let you see the problem (in the correct case, both square brackets in the output must be on the same line and without spaces).

Comment: @Inspired your guess is correct. thank you :)

Comment: @user3108337 Suggest you submit your own answer and accept it to complete this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a problem with newline characters being left on the input, you can just apply a simple check for the newline character and remove it if present:

```
size_t ln = strlen(data) - 1;
if ((ln > 0) && (data[ln] == '\n'))
    data[ln] = '\0';
for (i=0; i< 2;i++)
{
  if(strcmp(domainNames[i], data)==0)
  {
    strcat(msg, IP[i]);
    strcat(msg, "#");
    found = true;
  }
```

Because you're getting your input (`data`) from an external source, it would probably serve you well to thoroughly verify this prior to doing anything with it. Make a new function and pass data to it, verify you've stripped newlines, make sure there are no white space characters, make sure it ends with `".com"` or whatever... anything that comes from an external source should be validated to the best of your ability before using it, not only to help with debugging, but also to avoid attacks (intentional or not).

Also, just a slight (possible) optimization for you, if `msg` is empty prior to this function, you can always just check for a `0` length and remove the extra `found` Boolean that way.